# Google Adsense records current balance as negative value

Tags: google-adsense

I have Google Adsense several years ago and I have gotten purchased from Google several times too. One of my websites has been stopped showing ads (I manage to upgrade it and it is an welcome page only).

From long time I have not login to my Adsense account, but today I have login in and I found the total balance is **-$86.53 USD** as shown in the screen shot:

[image]

What's happening there? Do I have lost my balance? What I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below attachment is from Official Adsense Team.It is a glitch in their system nothing to be worried about.It will be fixed very soon!

[image]

[Latest News,Trending Topics on Info Buzz](http://theinfobuzz.com)

[Music Streaming Website - PCILY](http://pcily.com)